# Change the font size of Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio (2012 in my case), is it possible to decrease (or increase) the font size of a user's Solution Explorer? I'd like to decrease it to save screen space a bit.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

1. Go to  Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors
2. In "Show Settings for" chose "Environment Font"
3. In "Font" replace Automatic to  for example,  Arial and change size.

Change the font size of that setting, all Font size in the Explorers (Solution Explorer, Server Explorer and Toolbox) and menus will change.

Comment: It works for me for some time and then reverts to the default `Automatic`.

Comment: Choosing a condensed font gives you so much more room, especially on a narrow screen

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time looking for this.  So many things can be set up in this IDE, it's easy for newcomers to get lost.  Now back to couch coding... ;-)

Comment: It doesn't seem that this changes the size of the font in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Whats the default font used in VS? I only want to increase the size, but keep the font type.

Comment: The Segoe UI font seems to be the default Environment Font in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: ᵗʰᵃⁿᵏ ʸᵒᵘ ˢᵗᵃⁿᶦˢˡᵃᵛ

Answer (score 2):

You can set that in [Tools, Options](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fd12e24-280a-455f-8d9f-458708478e42/set-solution-explorer-fontsize-in-vs2012?forum=vssetup).

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I got really small fonts when opening .CS files, small font in Package Manager Console, small font in Find window (opens by Ctrl+F), but other fonts (like fonts for .TS files) were fine. I was able to put custom font size through Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors but I had to set the size to be 14 instead of the default 9 value and it helped for .CS editor but hurt the .TS editor and it did not modify the font in the Find window.

The only solution in my case was using CTRL + Mouse Wheel Up functionality to enlarge the fonts. I was able to return to the default font sizes everywhere and it also adjusted my Find window font size.